# Angular Universal Upgrade 8 -> 9 SSR build. Going down a error rabbit hole

Tags: angular

So I am in the process upgrading from 8 to 9 and ive solved various error during this update but I feel like I am going a rabbit hole of updates that are starting to make no sense. I am running my site with npm run build:ssr && npm run serve:ssr. The build is successful but when I go to the site locally I receive some errors.

The latest error I received
`No NgModule metadata found for 'AppModule'` I was able to resolve this issue by adding `"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,` to my tsconfig.json file. This resolved the error but another error came up which is `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open C:\xampp\htdocs\angular\background.video.component.html'` I know the file path to the template is correct because if run ng serve and run the site everything loads correctly. I am pretty puzzled as to why this is happening.

My background video component looks like this

```
import {timer as observableTimer,  Subscription, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { PLATFORM_ID, Inject, Component, Input, AfterViewInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformBrowser} from '@angular/common';

// Services
import {
  WindowRefService
} from '../../services/index';

@Component({
    selector: 'background-video',
    templateUrl: './background.video.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./background.video.component.scss'],
    providers: []
})
export class BackgroundVideoComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    private window;
    public isBrowser:boolean = false;
    public vidFontColor:string = 'black';
    public vid:HTMLVideoElement;
    public element;
    public vidSource:any;

    @Input("src")
    public source;

    @Input("poster")
    public posterSrc;

    @Input("loop")
    public shouldLoop;

    @Input("callback")
    public callback:Function;

    constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) platformId:string, private el:ElementRef, private windowRef:WindowRefService) {
      this.isBrowser = isPlatformBrowser(platformId);
      if(this.isBrowser) this.window = windowRef.nativeWindow;
      this.element = el;
    }

    ngOnInit() {
      this.vidSource = this.convertSourceByWindowSize(this.source);
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
      if(this.isBrowser) {
          this.vid = this.element.nativeElement.querySelector('video') as HTMLVideoElement;

        if (this.shouldLoop) {
          this.vid.loop = true;
        }
        // this.vid.addEventListener('canplaythrough', function() {
        //   this.play();
        // }, false);

        let timer = observableTimer(0, 250);
        timer.subscribe(() => {
          if (this.callback) {
            this.callback(this.vid);
          }
        });
      }
    }

    convertSourceByWindowSize(videoPath:string):string {
      let string:string = "480";
      if(this.isBrowser) {
        if (this.window.innerWidth <= 720) {
          string = "480";
        }
        else if (this.window.innerWidth <= 1366) {
          string = "720";
        }
        else {
          string = "1080";
        }
      }       

      string = videoPath+string;

      return string;
    }
}
```

Looks like your average component right? So I am not sure what the issue is. I am also posting my server.ts file and tsconfig.json file although I think both of them are fine.

server.ts

```
 import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import 'reflect-metadata';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
// Express Engine
import {ngExpressEngine} from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
// Import module map for lazy loading
import {provideModuleMap} from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';
import * as express from 'express';
import {join} from 'path';

// Faster server renders w/ Prod mode (dev mode never needed)
enableProdMode();

// Express server
const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;
const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist');

// * NOTE :: leave this as require() since this file is built Dynamically from webpack
const {AppServerModule, LAZY_MODULE_MAP} = require('./dist/server/main');

// Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine)
app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
  bootstrap: AppServerModule,
  providers: [
    provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
  ]
}));

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser'));

// Example Express Rest API endpoints
// app.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
// Server static files from /browser
app.get('*.*', express.static(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser'), {
  maxAge: '1y'
}));

// All regular routes use the Universal engine
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', { req });
});

// Start up the Node server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.